# java running jar via cronjob

Tags: java, cron

I want to setup a Minecraft server, which automatically starts up on system startup.

I use the following script to manually run: /home/mc_ftb/server/start.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -jar /home/mc_ftb/server/mcpc-plus-1.5.2-R0.2-forge716-B527.jar nogui
```

The cron to start it on start up looks like that:

```
mc_ftb  Ja  ~/server/start.sh
```

This structure already worked with other mods, like Tekkit, but now with a FTB (NewWorld) mod, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelaunchLog.resetLoggingHandlers(FMLRelaunchLog.java:212)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelaunchLog.configureLogging(FMLRelaunchLog.java:191)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelaunchLog.log(FMLRelaunchLog.java:242)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelaunchLog.info(FMLRelaunchLog.java:274)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelauncher.setupHome(FMLRelauncher.java:164)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelauncher.relaunchServer(FMLRelauncher.java:147)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelauncher.handleServerRelaunch(FMLRelauncher.java:45)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.main(MinecraftServer.java:1622)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Starting the script in a terminal as mc_ftb works fine, but even not with the cronjob, I already tried to start it via `exce java ...`.

The script and the jar file are +x'ed. I'm using the actual stable Debian.

Comment: Any chance that you forgot to define an environment variable or something? In any event, you should report a bug to the plugin author.

Comment: I don't know, while the installation of the mod I didn't set any variable

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a 'source /etc/profile' as the first line in your script, this will load the environment variables first.

So replace

```
#! /bin/sh
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -jar /home/mc_ftb/server/mcpc-plus-1.5.2-R0.2-forge716-B527.jar
```

with

```
#! /bin/sh
source /etc/profile
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -jar /home/mc_ftb/server/mcpc-plus-1.5.2-R0.2-forge716-B527.jar
```

Comment: I tried, now it additionally mentioned: `/home/mc_ftb/server/start.sh: 2: /home/mc_ftb/server/start.sh: source: not found`

Comment: Strange you don't have source, no prob try add a . its the same as source, so replace 'source /etc/profile' with '. /etc/profile', note the space between the . and '/etc/profile'

Comment: `. /etc/profile` works instead of source, but the problem is still the same